# Facebook PHP integration not working. Need light at the end of the tunnel

Tags: php, database, facebook

So, I've been researching and working on this PHP that retrieves the user information from Facebook (if logged on) and stores it into my database.

However, when I load the page on my browser, it is completely blank. I have included the facebook.php SDK file in the same directory as the facebook_signup.php file (code shown below). I would greatly appreciate if someone helped be figure out why this is not working.

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';// this line calls our facebook.php file that is the 
//core of PHP facebook API

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => '******',
  'secret' => '******',
  'cookie' => true,
)); // all we are doing is creating an array for facebook to use with our 
//app id and app secret in and setting the cookie to true
try {
  $me = $facebook->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  error_log($e);
} // this code is saying if the session to the app is created use 
//the $me as a selector for the information or die
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 
'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Facebook APP</title>
</head>

<body>
<? if ($facebook->getSession()) { ?>
<form action='signup.php' method='post'>
<fieldset class='field_name'>
<label>First Name</label>
<input class='name' name='first_name' type='text' value='<? if     ($facebook->getSession())
 {echo $me['first_name'];}else{echo'First Name';} ?>' />
</fieldset>
<fieldset class='field_name'>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input class='name' name='last_name' type='text' value='<? if ($facebook->getSession())
 {echo $me['last_name'];}else{echo'Last Name';} ?>' />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label>Email Address</label>
<input name='email' type='text' value='<? if ($facebook->getSession()) 
{echo $me['email'];}else{echo'email address';} ?>' />
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='submit' />
</fieldset>
</form>
<? } else {
  ?>
<p>Sign up with Facebook <fb:login-button perms='email'> Connect</fb:login-button>
It only takes a few seconds</p>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
      <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
      <script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:'******', cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload(); //will reload your page you are on
      });
      </script> 
 <? }
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should update [PHP-SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/) to [latest version](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk), but be prepared to change code, since there is no method `getSession` in new PHP-SDK. You should use [`getUser`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/) method to get user id. And probably better doing request to Graph API only if user is logged in...

```
if ($facebook->getUser()){
  // User is logged in, issue request to Graph API
  try {
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
} else {
  // User isn't logged in, display login-button
}
```

Comment: It is updated. I have also used the example PHP available on Github and it does not work. The page appears blank for the example as well. All other PHP files that I have run perfectly fine.